# Convert powers of trigonometric functions to linear sum of multiple angles

Tags: sympy

I cannot figure out if sympy has any functions to convert powers of trigonometric functions to a linear combination of multiple angles. For example, `sin(x)**4` can be written as `(3/2 - 2*cos(2*x) + 1/2 * cos(4*x))/4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working this way:

```
simplify(expand((sin(x)**4).rewrite(exp)))
```

Comment: It does not work for sin(x)**6: expand((sin(x)**6).rewrite(exp)).rewrite(cos)